# Datetime and sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Here's my T-SQL code where I'm having issues with `datetime`

OPEN @form_dates
FETCH NEXT FROM @form_dates INTO @cid, @regdate, @compdate

/* PRINT @regdate
PRINT @compdate
This is correctly having values in datetime. eg: Mar 28 2012  6:03PM
PRINT @courseno 
*/

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 
N'update tblname set cs' + CAST (@cid AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_begin = @rstring , cs' + CAST (@cid AS VARCHAR(10))+ '_end = @cstring where UserID = '+ CAST (@tempID AS VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@rstring datetime, @cstring datetime'

EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @ParmDefinition, 
@rstring = @regdate, @cstring = @compdate

`I have the values of @regdate and @compdate fetched from a cursor and are of the format 
    Jan  3 2012  2:30PM
    Mar 28 2012  6:03PM
but these values are not reflecting in procedure output where I get the output:`

update tblname set cs32_begin = @rstring , cs32_end = @cstring where UserID  = 419

Thanks.^

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Please show the definition of `@SQL, @regdate and @compdate`, and explain the cursor and the query where the values originate from. You're asking us to troubleshoot this completely blind.

Comment: And what happens when you simplify (e.g. the example I gave, where you just `SELECT`)? I also don't understand what you mean by "these values are not reflecting in procedure output" - how exactly are you getting the output in the last line of your code sample? Are you using `PRINT @SQL`? If so, keep in mind that `@SQL` does not replace the values inside the string after you use `sp_executeSQL`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with data types, datetime or the cursor. This is just <strike>sloppy</strike>inconsistent variable naming. Outside you call them:

```
@regstring
@compstring
```

Inside you call them:

```
@rstring
@cstring
```

So try being consistent, one way or the other:

```
SET @SQL = N'update tblname set cs' + CAST (@cid AS VARCHAR(10)) 
+ '_begin = @rstring , cs' + CAST (@cid AS VARCHAR(10))
+ '_end = @cstring where UserID = '+ CAST (@tempID AS VARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500)
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@rstring datetime, @cstring datetime'

EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @ParamDefinition, 
@rstring = @regdate, @cstring = @compdate
^^-------------------^^
```

**EDIT**

This works fine for me:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT _begin = @rstring , _end = @cstring;';

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500)
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@rstring datetime, @cstring datetime'

DECLARE @regdate DATETIME = GETDATE(), @compdate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE());

EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @ParmDefinition, 
@rstring = @regdate, @cstring = @compdate;
```

Results:

```
_begin                   _end
-----------------------  -----------------------
2012-06-13 10:28:47.657  2012-06-14 10:28:47.657
```

I don't see a way for your output to still contain the literal "@rstring" and not get properly replaced by the parameter, unless you still have a spelling or other variable name inconsistency. I suspect there is more to this query than what you're showing us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I accidentally posted that inconsistent code.
But it doesnt work with the right parameters either.

Comment: @RohanWarkad great, can you fix the code sample in your question, and show us the output you receive now?

Comment: I keep getting this at the output  `code`
update tblname set cs30_begin = @rstring , cs30_end = @cstring where UserID = 275 `code`

when im actually expecting `code` @rstring; @cstring `code` to have the respective variable values

Comment: @RohanWarkad *PLEASE* update the question. Nobody wants to try to decipher code samples in a comment.

Comment: @RohanWarkad please stop attempting to update my answer. *Update your question.*